# Reducing an inseparable polynomial over the same field to a separable polynomial over a field

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field, separable-extension

Description: Let $F$ be a perfect field and $p(x)$ a polynomial over $F$ with multiple roots. Show that there is a polynomial $q(x)$ over $F$ whose distinct roots are the same as the distinct roots of $p(x)$, but that occur in $q(x)$ only as simple roots.